# Positioning overlapping canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've got a page that is supposed to display a line graph.  There is a title at the top, the graph in the middle, then a table below them.  It is laid out roughly like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <canvas1></canvas>
    <canvas2></canvas>
</div>
<div>
    <table></table>
</div>
```

Right now each of the 'div' blocks are staying separate from each other, which is good.  However, the two canvas's, despite having different z-index values, are next to each other instead of stacking on top.  I've read that their position values should both be set to absolute, but whenever I do this, the table immediately moves on top of the canvas.

What position and display values do I need to set to the div's and the elements inside them to get the canvasses on top of each other (both are the same dimensions) without anything else stacking on top of their div?

Edit:  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BUZ9/)

Comment: Posting a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** would help.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

Wrap the 2 canvases inside a wrapper div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvasBottom" width=300 height=200></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasTop" width=300 height=200></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

Position the 2 canvases at the same top & left relative to the wrapper div.

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
#canvasTop,#canvasBottom{
    position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be getting the canvases on top of each other, but for some reason it's distorting my graph.  I will have to investigate further.  But this is a step in the right direction!

Comment: CSS can distort the canvas content.  So, try hard-coding the canvas width/height as I've done in my revised answer.

Comment: That got the dimensions right.  Now, though, I've got the table appearing the bottom of my graph.  If all the div's are set to display: block, that shouldn't happen, right?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use flex-box to float stacked canvases to perfection. Note: you'll need to use "display: flex" for the entire layout including HTML and BODY elements, plus any parent containers/ divs.

```
#canvasWrapper {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }

canvas {
    position: absolute;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the "position" attribute of your two canvas to "absolute", then the two canvas would stick to the parent element, say, your div.
  The reason why the table moves on top of your canvas is that the table, in a sense, "neglected" your canvas and was located as if there is no canvas.
  What you should do is keep the absolute position value of the canvas and set the "top" value of table to the height of your canvas, then the table would be just beneath the canvas.
  let me give you an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Animal World</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            width: 50%;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #dog {
            z-index: 1;

        }
        #cat {
            z-index: 0;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        table{
            background-color: rgb(196, 255, 216);
            position: relative;
            top: 100px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        caption{
            font-weight: bolder;
            font-size: 2em;
            background-color:  rgb(196, 255, 216);
            border: 1px groove lightblue;
        }
        td,th{
            border: 1px groove lightblue;
           
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Animal</h1>
    </div>
    <div id = "canvas">
        <canvas id = "dog"></canvas>
        <canvas id = "cat"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        var dog = document.getElementById('dog');
        var cat = document.getElementById('cat');
        var dog_ctx = dog.getContext('2d');
        var cat_ctx = dog.getContext('2d');
        dog_ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        dog_ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
    </script>
    
    <div class = "table">
            <table>
                <caption>Animal</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Dog</th>
                    <th>Panda</th>
                    <th>Cat</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>middle</td>
                    <td>large</td>
                    <td>small</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```