# HTML Canvas - How to have multiple Canvas Layers Overlapping Without Association?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, layer

I'm trying to make 2 separate canvas elements that overlap one another without them interfering.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Dodge 'n Block</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas1">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="myCanvas2">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js">  </script>

</body>
```

Javascript

```
var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");

var c2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
```

Now when I try to do `ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, c2.width, c2.height);` it clears the whole canvas, including canvas c1, ctx1.

Is there a way I can do this?

Feel free to ask any questions, thank you!

Comment: That code does not seem right. Shouldn't you be using `var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");` and `var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");`? What is `c`? I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: My mistake, I was writing a quick example of my work. Good eye

Comment: This should not happen (both canvases being cleared). Make sure you are indeed using different contexts for both. I can't see any other way for what you are describing to happen.

Comment: Why don't you keep a reference to two canvases in memory then draw both of them to a single canvas using `ctx.drawImage`? This is the way multiple stacked canvases are meant to be displayed instead of hacking around using CSS to overlay them.

Comment: See this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414288/positioning-overlapping-canvas/22414928#22414928) if you want to use CSS to overlay both canvases at the same position. See this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330860/merging-canvas-and-background/30331268#30331268) if you want to merge the contents of one canvas onto another canvas.

Comment: I do use ctx.drawImage, but in specific times I'm trying to keep the background image constant without redrawing it multiple times eating up power, rather draw it ones, then on a secondary canvas do any animation and such.

Comment: Sergiu was spot on, I had c instead of c1/c2. Thank you, but now they overlap the whole screen white.

Comment: I got it now fellas, thank you!